# How to set the contentSize of a NSScrollView in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, nsscrollview

I would like to add the size to the content of my scroll view but the `contentSize` field is { read only } and I cannot let the view scroll.

What could I do?! Is there any other solution?

[image]

Comment: So it is iOS or Mac OS? Use CGSizeMake instead of NSSize for UIScrollView .

Comment: The problem is that this field is not writable, you can only read it. Even if you use CGSizeMake it will not work. It's a OS X project.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScrollView/contentSize

Comment: For `NSScrollView` you need to set frame of its `documentView`, look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Basics.html

Comment: I din't know about documentView! It works great! Thanks!